# Slope of displacement-time graph

Tags: kinematics

[image]

Slope of x-t graph= velocity

Therefore, $v_{A}$=$\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$

and $v_{B}$=$\sqrt{\frac{3}{1}}$

$\frac{V_{A}}{V_{b}}$=$\frac{1}{3}$

but the answer given is (A), am I missing something or the answer is wrong?

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not making a mistake. The velocity ratios **should be** $$\frac{1}{3}$$ because we can take the gradient to be the velocity time graph and gradient is equal to tan(theta) so the ratio becomes $$\frac{tan(30)}{tan(60)}$$ which is equal to 1/3.